# Is there a plane that passes through a pair of lines that have no points in common?

Tags: geometry

I'm reading a book on geometry in Spanish by Ana Berenice Guerrero (see [here](http://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Geometr%C3%ADa.html?id=KQPu54kgeKwC), p. 18,19). So, there's this theorem that says that given a pair of lines with no points in common there's only one plane that have both of them.

I have read the proof a lot of times and I feel like there's something wrong. Then my frustration comes from the fact that I can imagine a pair of lines in the space that are not parallel and with no points in common. I cannot visualize the plane that contain both lines. Maybe someone can help me understand this.

[image]

Comment: No, it's not possible to have one plane containing two skew lines. Remember, lines in a plane are either parallel or intersect. Maybe the easiest example to visualize is that of two non-intersecting perpendicular lines in space.

Comment: What are the axioms?

Comment: @GitGud Hilbert's Axioms

Comment: From what I understand from the proof, she just proved that there is at most one such plane. She didn't prove existence. Is there any remark at the beginning of the book that says that "um único" means 'at least one and exactly one'?

Comment: @GitGud I was thinking the same, at least when I read the OP's statement "only one plane". It's not "exactly one plane". But as far as I can understand the proof in the book (with my limited Spanish), it positively says "there is a unique plane". I wonder if this statement isn't strong?

Comment: @M.Vinay I think it's common in [synthetic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_geometry) to treat quantification as 'exact', that is, if it is said there is 'one', then there is exactly one; if it it said there are two, then there are exactly two, and so on.

Comment: @GitGud Unfurtunately there are no remarks about it, yet for the context in the proof I can say that "pasa un único plano" means there's one plane and such a plane is unique. Also in the "tesis" part she says "Existe un único plano..." which literally means there exists a unique plane.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, the proof is incorrect. I have only a rudimentary understanding of Spanish, but it seems the proof *assumes* that both the planes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ contain all the points of both the lines $a$ and $c$. This is only an assumption, and is not valid. If this assumption were part of the statement of the theorem, it would be okay, for then the theorem would be "If at all there is a plane containing two lines with no common points, then this plane is unique".

Answer (score 3):

Interesting logic. I'm not sure what they were thinking. Here is a translation of the false theorem:

> **Theorem 1.3.6.** *For two non-intersecting lines, there is a unique intersecting plane*
>
> Let $a,c$ be non-intersecting lines. Then there exists a unique plane containing $a,c.$
>
> - Take unique points $A,B$ on $a$, and $C,D$ on $c$. Now $ABD$ are not all on the same line. Likewise $CDB$ are not all on the same line.
> - By 'axiom 1.2.5,' $ABD$ determine a unique plane $\alpha$ and $CDB$ determine a unique plane $\beta$.
> - Assume WLOG that $a$ is contained in $\alpha$ and $c$ is contained in $\beta$.
> - Now both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ contain both $ABD$ and $CDB$. But since the planes defined by $ABD$ and $CDB$ are unique, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the same.
> - Therefore there is a unique plane containing $a,c$.

The error occurs on the 4th step. There is no reason that $ABD$ should also contain $C$, or that $CDB$ should contain $A$. For that we would need the additional assumption that the lines are parallel. (Or, if we are more concerned about the *uniqueness* of the plane, we would instead need to assume something like 'there exists some plane with all 4 points in it')

Unless its not a focus of the course, I would be extremely wary of a textbook with this level of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well. It is only possible to construct a View where the two lines appear to be parallel, and there exists only one such view. So there is some truth in it .. However if you were to have a PLANE.. it will have only 2 points as the two lines are skewed ... so in conclusion, view = possible, Plane = impossible.